Is it always possible to connect the endpoints of a smooth injective path, so the resulting path is smooth, closed and simple?
Motivation
The motivation for this question arises from the following problem: Is there a closed, simple, and infinitely differentiable path on the (complex) plane such that every straight line has a parallel line that intersects the path at infinitely many points?
To approach this, I attempt to construct such a path by first defining $\gamma: [-1, 1] \to \mathbb{C}$ as follows:
$$
\gamma(t) =
\begin{cases}
\cos\left(\frac{1}{t^2}\right)\exp\left(-\frac{1}{t^2}\right) + \sin\left(\frac{1}{t^2}\right)\exp\left(-\frac{1}{t^2}\right)i, & \text{if } -1 \leq t < 0, \\
0, & \text{if } t = 0, \\
\cos\left(\frac{1}{t^2}\right)\exp\left(-\frac{1}{t^2} + \varepsilon t^2\right) + \sin\left(\frac{1}{t^2}\right)\exp\left(-\frac{1}{t^2} + \varepsilon t^2\right)i, & \text{if } 0 < t \leq 1.
\end{cases}
$$
This path is infinitely differentiable ($C^{\infty}$, defined below), simple (injective) if $0 < \varepsilon < 2\pi$, and intersects every straight line through $0$ infinitely many times. However, it is not closed. To create a closed path, I need a path $\eta : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{C}$ connecting $\gamma(1)$ to $\gamma(-1)$ such that $\gamma \eta$, the concatenation of $\gamma$ and $\eta$ (defined below), forms an infinitely differentiable, closed simple path.

The Problem
The above discussion leads to the following general question:

If a path $\gamma$ on euclidean space is $C^k$ (resp. $C^k$-smooth), injective, is there a path $\eta$ such that $\gamma \eta$ is closed, simple, and $C^k$ (resp. $C^k$-smooth)?

Here $C^k$ (resp. $C^k$-smooth) could be either $C^{\infty}$ (resp. $C^{\infty}$-smooth) or $C^k$ (resp. $C^k$-smooth) for some positive integer $k$.

Relevant Definitions
Concatenation
For two paths $f, g: [0, 1] \to X$ in a topological space $X$, if $f(1) = g(0)$, their concatenation $f g$ is defined as:
$$
fg(t) =
\begin{cases}
f(2t), & \text{if } 0 \leq t \leq 1/2, \\
g(2t - 1), & \text{if } 1/2 \leq t \leq 1.
\end{cases}
$$
"Smoothness" conditions

A path $\gamma: [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is $C^k$ if it is $k$-times differentiable on $[0, 1]$ (using one-sided derivatives at $t = 0$ and $t = 1$). If $\gamma$ forms a closed loop (i.e., $\gamma(0) = \gamma(1)$), the one-sided derivatives at the endpoints must coincide: $\gamma^{(n)}(0^+) = \gamma^{(n)}(1^-)$ for $1 \leq n \leq k$.

A path $\gamma$ is $C^k$-smooth if it is $C^k$ and $\gamma'(t) \neq 0$ for all $t \in [0, 1]$.

A path is $C^\infty$ (resp. $C^\infty$-smooth) if it is $C^k$ (resp. $C^k$-smooth) for all $k \geq 1$.



Edit Summary

Added what it means for a path to be $C^k$ and $C^k$-smooth.
The problem originally consisted of a two-part question. First, I asked: "Given an infinitely differentiable path $\gamma: [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\gamma(0) \neq \gamma(1)$, does there exist a path $\eta: [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}^n$ connecting $\gamma(1)$ to $\gamma(0)$ such that the concatenated path $\gamma \eta$ is closed and infinitely differentiable?" This part was removed, as it suffices to concatenate $\gamma(t)$ with $\gamma(1-t)$.
Generalized the problem to  various "smoothness" conditions.
Removed the possible extensions of the problem.


Please specify what you mean by "infinitely-differentiable path" in the original problem: there exists an infinitely differentiable parametrization $\gamma(t)$ or there exists such a parametrization with $\gamma'(t)\neq 0$?

Thank you for pointing that out @Alexandre, I will clarify that. In the motivating problem, it would be interesting to come up with smooth paths ($\gamma'(t)\neq 0$), and it is possible to construct a $C^1$-smooth path that has the desired property. Also, I just realized that the first part of my problem is trivial, it would suffice to concatenate $\gamma(t)$ with $\gamma(1 - t)$ if the resulting path is not required to be simple. It is the second part of the problem that is interesting, and it can be asked of many kinds of paths ($C^1$, $C^1$-smooth, etc).

All problems are doable, but it think to answer the question in the motivation you don't need the constrictions in the subsequeent problems.

I heavily revised my question, I hope it is clearer now. @Pietro, could you please specify which priors in my question are unnecessary? They would all be necessary as far as I understand.

ops, my comment above has been  made obscure by the auto-correct. I just meant that the question in the Motivation may be easier than the subsequent problems (as a side note: it should be better to ask one question per post)

Great! I did not mean to ask about the "motivating problem" on this post, maybe my discussion of it is too detailed. Should I make it more brief?

If $\Gamma\subset \mathbb R^2$ is a $C^1$   regular simple closed curve  (the image of a $C^1$ injective  $\gamma:\mathbb S^1\to\mathbb R^2$ with $\dot\gamma(t)\neq0 ;\forall t$), I think,  the  set of all straight lines $\ell$ that  have  infinitely many intersections with  $\Gamma$ is at most countable.

I think the answer to the Problem is yes (in both versions), and you don’t need to assume the existence of $\xi$.  There is a nbd of the curve $\gamma$ which is foliated by  $C^k$ curves; you can cut these curves with the normal  at the enpoints of $\gamma$ (the resulting  picture  looks like a   maccherone). Then you can connect $\gamma$ and one of these close curves  by a small curve on both sides,  and obtain a  close simple curve.

Now I see that $\xi$ always exists given the other priors. I was thinking of proving the existence of $\xi$ and then applying a density argument: some sufficiently smooth $\eta$ should exist as close as we want from $\xi$ (with the same endpoints, of course).

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Solution of your original question: A smooth curve cannot intersect infinitely many times lines in all directions.
Let $\gamma: T\to \Gamma$ be the parametrization
of your curve, where $T$ is the unit circle,
$\gamma\in C^\infty$ and $\gamma'(t)\neq 0$ for all $t$. Then
$$f(t)=\frac{\gamma'(t)}{|\gamma'(t)|}$$
is a $C^\infty$ map $T\to T$. Applying Sard's Lemma,
we obtain that almost every value of $f$ is regular,
therefore, the $f$-preimage of almost every value
is finite.
On the other hand, if the curve intersects
a line in direction $\theta\in T$ infinitely many times, then it must have
infinitely many points where the direction
of the tangent line to $\Gamma$ is $\theta$.
Indeed, suppose that $t_k$ are the points
where $\gamma(t_k)$ intersects some line $\ell$ with direction $\theta$, wlog $\theta$ is the horizontal direction and $\ell$ is the $x$-axis. Let $t^*$ be an accumulation point of $t_k$. Then in a neighborhood of $t_k$, $\Gamma$ is a graph of a smooth function, $\phi(x)$ which intersect the horizontal axis infinitely many times in any neighborhood of $\gamma(t^*)$,
so by Rolle's theorem, $\phi'(t)=0$ infinitely many times in a neighborhood of
$t^*$.
The best reference for Sard's Lemma is
J. Milnor, Topology from the differentiab;e viewpoint, UP of Virginia, Charlottesville, 1965,
